# Opening images in TIFF format in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis

I am trying to open satellite imagery of several countries. The image descends in TIFF format. When I open it with QGIS 3.12 it opens in the form below. As far as I investigate, I do symbology settings, but it still doesn't happen. What should I do?

[image]

---

[image]

I am trying to open satellite imagery of several countries. The image descends in tiff format. When I open it with QGIS it opens in the form below.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? What is the original image you're aiming to load in to QGIS? Is it also a TIF or not?